# £ symbol encoded as =A3500 in email

Tags: email, encoding

I have a python script that parses email sent to a support address and stores it in a database. I got an error in my logs where it does the database insert
Incorrect string value: '\xA3500 w...
When I view the email in thunderbird I see the offending character rendered as a pound symbol £ and I can tell from context that that is indeed what was intended by the sender. But when I look at the raw eml file I see
=A3500 where the pound symbol should be.
The header in the email says  charset="iso-8859-1". I suspect the email as sent really doesn't conform to the spec, but I need to at least try to handle nonconforming emails rather than just erroring out.

Any ideas as to what is happening here and what to do about it? It must be possible to parse the email as intended, since thnderbird is doing it.

Comment: That is brexit for you. Our currency is getting devalued to a list of numbers and letters

Answer (score 0):

I had based my code on the example here
https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html
of decoding a multipart message. It turns out that after I got a string with
body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
the "deocode" is just removing the content transfer encoding, I needed to add a second decode for the charset
                charset = part.get_content_charset()

```
             body = body.decode(charset)
```